# Using a git submodule as an android library

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I've seen a few similar questions to this but have not found a definitive answer and hoping someone could help. I have an android project with a subdirectory that is a git submodule that I want to use as a library (it is a android library project). The problem is that the only way that i've found for Eclipse to let me add it as a library is to first import the submodule into my workspace. If I do that I have it in my workspace and as a subdirectory.

What's the trick to make eclipse "see" this subdirectory as a library and import it without first importing into the workspace as a separate project.

Comment: If you don't want it in the workspace, check if the `jar` is available to download (probably in `bin/`)

Comment: This is a project library that I have also created. I don't want it as  as jar because I want it to pick up updates from the submodule's git repo.